# Why there is no ValueNotifierBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I would like to have ValueNotifierBuilder, but currently it doesn't exist. Is there any plan that this will be added?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What are `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder` not doing a `ValueNotifierBuilder` would do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `ValueListenableBuilder` which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

It rebuilds from any `ValueListenable` (`ValueNotifier` is one).

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: valueNotifier,
  builder: (context, value, child) {
    return Text('$value');
})
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

It has now been added to the framework, under the name of `ValueListenableBuilder`

---

There's already one, but not under the name of `ValueNotifierBuilder`.

It is `AnimatedBuilder`, which is compatible with any `Listenable`. And `ValueNotifier` is one (but `ScrollController` and many others are too).

```
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: valueNotifier,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(valueNotifier.value.toString()),
        child,
      ],
    );
  },
  child: Text("Hello World")
)
```

Comment: I know that I can use AnimatedBuilder, but the second parameter of the builder is a widget, but I would rather have that the second parameter is a value ...

Comment: you have direct access to the value of a `valueListenable` using `valueListenable.value`. You don't need it. Which is why it's not passed as parameter

Comment: with StreamBuilder you also have direct access to the stream, but you are still expecting the right value in the builder ...

Comment: @PeterZagoranski In a `Stream` you do not have access to the object without the builder.

Comment: Indeed. It's impossible to get the current value of a `Stream`, as opposed to most `Listenable`. Anyway, it's not even possible to make a builder with `value` as parameter. `Listenable` interface doesn't even have a value to begin with. Only `ValueListenable` do

Comment: I was looking for ValueNotifier with child property. Thanks.